# Firebase retrieve data shows only one result

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a data of objects and the result shows on the console but it only shows one result(the last result) on the page.

```
$http.get('/users').success(function(data) {
        $scope.username = data; //assign data to username
        console.log(data);
});
```

And in my Jade template, i have

```
section(data-ng-controller='browse')
h4 hi
ul(data-ng-repeat='user in username')
li {{user}}
```

I want to loop through this data

```
 {
  "google: xxxxxxxxxxxxx" : {
    "name" : "ZZZ YYY",
    "profile" : {
      "briefProfile" : "Cost call",
      "career" : "Web Developer",
      "projects" : {
        "-JjtSgiwkqFxTxMv0Gip" : "http://zipper.com"
      }
    },
    "provider" : "google"
  },
  "google:xxxxxxxxxxx" : {
    "name" : "SSS TTT",
    "profile" : {
      "briefProfile" : "Desired Intelligence",
      "career" : "Consultant"
    },
    "provider" : "google"
  }
}
```

Thanks.(i'm not using angularFire).

Comment: Please update your question. As it is currently, it has nothing to do with Firebase since you're using `$http` to request your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `$http` service, then you're not using Firebase.

1. You are repeating the `ul` instead of the `li`. Also, `{{user}}` will be the whole user object, and you will see something like [Object object] on your page instead of a string. So call `{{user.name}}`.

   ```
   ul
   li(data-ng-repeat='user in users') {{user.name}}
   ```
2. Assuming that `$http` is there by mistake, and you meant to use Firebase instead, you probably want to start by reviewing the Firebase [Getting Started guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/)

   ```
   // Get a reference to users
   var ref = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/users');

   // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at users ref
   ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val());
     $scope.users = snapshot.val();
   }, function (errorObject) {
     console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
   });
   ```

Comment: OMG, i feel so stupid right now. It's so sad, i never realised that. The mistake was the `ul and li`. Thank you so much @Sinan and @Elias. I really appreciate.

Comment: i guess i forgot to pay attention to front-end code

Comment: Not a problem! The front-end code is a tricky one sometimes. I'd also suggest checking out the `ng-bind` directive. It's "nicer" than `{{ ... }}` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using AngularFire you should take a look at this:**

Instead of using $http.get try:

```
var data = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("URL"));
$scope.data = data;
```

Don't forget to add $firebaseArray as a dependency in your controller.

More info on AngularFire docs:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray

**If you're not using AngularFire take a look at this:**

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('YOUR-FIREBASE-URL/users/');
firebaseRef.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
    var data = dataSnapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    $scope.users = data;

    // Might need to use $digest to update $scope.
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

More about on() in Firebase docs:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html

Comment: Sorry, i'm not using angularFire :)

Comment: Hi @BabajideFowotade I've updated the answer above, take a look under "If you're not using AngularFire take a look at this:" Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @Elias i have tried what you asked, but sadly :( it still doesn't work. It still returns the last data only but the complete data on console.

Comment: Hi @BabajideFowotade Is it possible for you to show how the data looks like in the console? can you paste it here or somewhere and link to it?

Comment: This is an image of the data returned. http://s30.postimg.org/xs2odcoj5/Screen_Shot_2015_03_09_at_12_23_30_AM.png 

When i then do an ng-repeat, the last data is shown on the page.