# My app only shows one item of retrieved data

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular

I'm building a little app using firebase and Angular 2.

Things are going well but now I'm facing a little issue. When I retrieve data, in the console I have all my data (3 objects). But the app only shows one of them (the last in the database).

I already looked at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929840/firebase-retrieve-data-shows-only-one-result).

But its seems to be not the same problem

I'm retrieving data this way:

```js
loadTask() {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
        this.usersRef = new Firebase('https://FBRUL.firebaseio.com/users/');
        this.publicationRef = new Firebase('https://FBRUL.firebaseio.com/task/');
        this.publicationRef.orderByKey().equalTo(key).on("child_added", (snapshot) =>{
          this.publications = snapshot.key();
          this.publicationRef.child(this.publications).on("child_added", snapshot => {
            this.__publi = snapshot.val();
            this.__key = snapshot.key();
            let publicio = [];
            this.publicationnass = {nom: this.__publi.nom, skills: this.__publi.skills, bugdet: this.__publi.budget, distance: Math.floor(distance), date: this.__publi.date, location: this.__publi.location, attribue: this.__publi.attribue, id1:this.publications, id: this.__key, offres: this.__publi.offres, user: this.__publi.user }
            publicio.push(this.publicationnass)
            observer.next(publicio)
          })
        })
    })
  })
 } 
}
```

and this is the plnkr of my case [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZWIcqCPODXwRQZLNovG?p=preview)

As you can see the data are all in the console, but only one is displayed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you provide to the observer an array with one element three times. That's why the observable received and ngFor displays only one element:

To prevent from this, you could externalize the `publicio` variable from the observable. This way, you will see the three elements successively received:

```
loadTask(){
  let publicio = []; // <-----
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance){
      this.usersRef = new Firebase('https://FBRUL.firebaseio.com/users/');
      this.publicationRef = new Firebase('https://FBRUL.firebaseio.com/task/');
      this.publicationRef.orderByKey().equalTo(key).on("child_added", (snapshot) =>{
        this.publications = snapshot.key();
        this.publicationRef.child(this.publications).on("child_added", snapshot => {
          this.__publi = snapshot.val();
          this.__key = snapshot.key();
          //let publicio = []; // <------
          this.publicationnass = {nom: this.__publi.nom, skills: this.__publi.skills, bugdet: this.__publi.budget, distance: Math.floor(distance), date: this.__publi.date, location: this.__publi.location, attribue: this.__publi.attribue, id1:this.publications, id: this.__key, offres: this.__publi.offres, user: this.__publi.user }
          publicio.push(this.publicationnass)
          observer.next(publicio)
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: hi @thierry sorry for the trouble but , how can i send all the datas without push method here ? with push method when i add something inside my datas , it call an another push method when i just want an update of this data.
so it create 2 same data into the view. how can i manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, apart from Thierry's answer. You could send the elements one at a time as objects not a arrays. Then,on your App component, you just push them to the posts array.

[Your Plunker fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/XfuN48pymtdpC6a0cTe6?p=preview)

```
return Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance){
        this.usersRef = new Firebase('https://jobandgo.firebaseio.com/users/');
        this.publicationRef = new Firebase('https://jobandgo.firebaseio.com/task/');
        this.publicationRef.orderByKey().equalTo(key).on("child_added", (snapshot) =>{
          this.publications = snapshot.key();
          this.publicationRef.child(this.publications).on("child_added", snapshot => {
            this.__publi = snapshot.val();
            this.__key = snapshot.key();
            // let publicio = []; 
            // I changed the below line from this.publicationnass = to let publicationnass because you dont need publicationnass to be on the class level
            let publicationnass = {nom: this.__publi.nom, skills: this.__publi.skills, bugdet: this.__publi.budget, distance: Math.floor(distance), date: this.__publi.date, location: this.__publi.location, attribue: this.__publi.attribue, id1:this.publications, id: this.__key, offres: this.__publi.offres, user: this.__publi.user }
            // no need for the line below
            // publicio.push(publicationnass)
            observer.next(publicationnass) 
          })
        })
    })
  })
```

then, on your app component:

```
constructor(public Dataservice: Dataservice) {
  this.Dataservice.loadTask().subscribe((res) => {
    this.posts.push(res)
    console.log(this.posts)
  })
}
```